# Comparing synchronization primitives (future, barrier, conditional var) - which one fits the best?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Trying to understand and compare synchronization primitives, like `std::future/std::promise`, `std::barrier` and `std::conditional_variable` - developing an intuition for which one to use when exactly.

I have this scenario where there are two threads synchronized via a flag. Basically, `A` expects `B` to signal upon setting a flag (`isSet` in the case of the conditional variable approach). And this is the idea I tried to replicate with `std::barrier` (which has no flag really but rather is sync'ed via arrive_and_wait)

I will present the possible solutions I came up with with each approach but need help deciding which one fits the best.

My understanding is future/promise is supposed to be used only once and not reused (which I'm doing in my approach and that may be why it's not a recommended route).

### Barrier

```
class A 
{
public:
    static std::barrier<> barrier;
    static std::mutex coutMutex; 
    static std::condition_variable cv;
    static bool isReady;
    
    void Wait() 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
                std::cout << "A - waiting for set\n";
                isReady = true;
            }
            
            cv.notify_one();

            barrier.arrive_and_wait();

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
                std::cout << "A - waiting for unset\n";
            }

            barrier.arrive_and_wait();
        }
    }
};

std::barrier<> A::barrier(2);
std::mutex A::coutMutex;
std::condition_variable A::cv;
bool A::isReady = false;

class B 
{
public:
    void Set() 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(A::coutMutex);
            A::cv.wait(lock, [] { return A::isReady; });
        }
        
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(A::coutMutex);
            std::cout << "B - Setting\n\n";
        }

        A::barrier.arrive_and_wait();
    }

    void Unset() 
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(A::coutMutex);
            std::cout << "B - Unsetting\n\n";
        }

        A::barrier.arrive_and_wait();
    }
};
```

---

### Conditional Variables

```
class A 
{
public:
    static std::mutex mtx; 
    static std::condition_variable cv;
    static bool isReady;
    static bool isSet;
    
    void Wait() 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                std::cout << "A - waiting for set\n";
                isReady = true;
            }
            
            cv.notify_one();
            
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(A::mtx);
                A::cv.wait(lock, [] { return isSet; });
            }
        
            
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                std::cout << "A - set\n";
                std::cout << "A - waiting for unset\n";
            }
            
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(A::mtx);
                cv.wait(lock, [] { return !isSet; });
            }
        }
    }
};

std::mutex A::mtx;
std::condition_variable A::cv;
bool A::isReady = false;
bool A::isSet = false;

class B 
{
public:
    void Set() 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(A::mtx);
            A::cv.wait(lock, [] { return A::isReady; });
        }
        
        
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(A::mtx);
            std::cout << "A is ready\n";
            std::cout << "B - Setting\n\n";
            A::isSet = true;
        }
        A::cv.notify_one();
    }

    void Unset() 
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(A::mtx);
            std::cout << "B - Unsetting\n\n";
            A::isSet = false;
        }
        A::cv.notify_one();
    }
};
```

### Future/Promise

[sample code](https://onlinegdb.com/ubjm5RAYj)

```
class A
{
public:
    static std::promise<bool> signalPromise;
    static std::promise<bool> readyPromise;
    static std::mutex promiseMutex;

    void Wait()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::future<bool> signalFuture;

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(promiseMutex);
                std::cout << "A - waiting for set\n";
                signalFuture = signalPromise.get_future();
                readyPromise.set_value(true);
            }

            // wait till flag is set
            signalFuture.wait();

            // Reset the promise for the next iteration
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(promiseMutex);
                signalPromise = std::promise<bool>();
                readyPromise = std::promise<bool>();
            }
        }
    }
};

std::promise<bool> A::signalPromise;
std::promise<bool> A::readyPromise;
std::mutex A::promiseMutex;

// B.hpp
class B
{
public:

    void Set()
    {
        std::promise<bool>& signalPromise = A::signalPromise;
        std::future<bool> readyFuture = A::readyPromise.get_future();
        
        readyFuture.wait();
        
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(A::promiseMutex);
            std::cout << "B - Setting\n\n";
            signalPromise.set_value(true);

            // Reset the promise for the next signal
            signalPromise = std::promise<bool>();
        }
    }

    void Unset()
    {
        std::promise<bool>& signalPromise = A::signalPromise;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(A::promiseMutex);
            std::cout << "B - Unsetting\n\n";
            signalPromise.set_value(false);

            // Reset the promise for the next signal
            signalPromise = std::promise<bool>();
        }
    }
};
```

Following is the driver code

```
int main() 
{
    A a;
    B b;

    std::thread threadA(&A::Wait, &a);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) 
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        b.Set();
        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        b.Unset();
    }

    threadA.join();
}
```

Comment: You're using a mutex for all of them, so ... ?

Comment: ........pardon?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively:

A future/promise is a handoff of an object from one thread to the next. Usually the thing being handed off is significant (as in a delivery truck giving you the package you ordered) but it doesn't have to be (as in a foot race where an otherwise useless baton is being handed off).

A barrier is like the starting line at a horse race. You wait for all the horses to get in their gates, and then they all start off (i.e., resume down the track) at the same time. If you leave the starting gate on the track, the horses will all line up again after they eventually complete one lap in staggered order, and then once they all arrive, they all start *again* at the same time.

A condition variable is like the kitchen service bell at diner. The order-taker puts the order on the counter, rings the bell, and runs off. The cook wakes up if they were asleep (or wanders over eventually if they were busy) and picks up the order. There might be multiple order-takers and/or cooks using the bell. How efficient the kitchen is depends on how well the order-takers and cooks work together, and even how many bells are used. The bell itself can only ring.

With a little imagination you can often implement one situation using the others. It's best to use the tool that matches the job, of course.

Which most closely describes what you are trying to accomplish? As best I can tell, it looks like you want to use a barrier. Your barrier code looks basically correct, but you don't need the condition variable or isReady flag since the barrier handles that.

In your condition variable approach, B does not know what A is actually doing. It's just hoping for the best. There's no guarantee that A transitions (sleeps don't count when determining correctness). This may or may not be your intent, since you never said what you actually wanted.

Your future/promise implementation is definitely not right. It is not managing the objects correctly and has race conditions. Remember, sleeps don't count when determining correctness. Threads will take the worst possible sequence.  B may extract the readyFuture from the same readyPromise twice. The signalPromise gets created three times for every one time the signalFuture is waited on.

Comment: Thanks. So something like this with barrier would make a good case?
https://onlinegdb.com/yYqtAeJBq

Comment: @xyf B::set() should only have one arrive_and_wait(). Barriers are based on the idea that all participants are in lock-step through the phases. All participants should arrive at the barrier the same number of times. See https://onlinegdb.com/WL2seIqWY

Comment: true but I want `A::Wait` to run first before `B` gets to run

Comment: You can use the same barrier to make B wait until A is finished initializing, but both threads need to have matching arrive_and_wait() calls. Think of arrive_and_wait() as a place where A and B shake hands. They both have to be there to do it, so you know exactly where _both_ threads are when they shake hands. Critically, they both have to agree on the _number_ of times they will shake hands (or one will be left hanging, or they'll mismatch and won't be where you think they are).

Comment: Can you help ensure that `A::Wait` gets to run first before `B` does? My understanding is that neither threads would proceed until they are aligned via `arrive_and_wait()` calls so that doesn't stop `B` from running first. (And that's why in my example I used conditional variable) https://onlinegdb.com/VqWAhJRLIq

Comment: You add a set up phase where A does its thing and then arrive_and_wait(), while B does nothing and then arrive_and_wait().
https://onlinegdb.com/V-KQK1UJz